# Crystal Report load very slow when running on different database than report file

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 SP2 with a C# .NET 4.0 application. In the application, we load Crystal Reports using this the Load method on ReportDocument:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(fileName);
```

This works fine when the database name that is embedded in the report is accessible, but when it's not (e.g. this is running in production or UAT, where the database names are different), this Load method is very slow. I think this is because Crystal is attempting to verify the report (or something like that) on the database that is embedded in the report.

Is there a way to turn off this behavior in Crystal or modify the report so that the database name is not embedded in it?

Thanks!

Comment: Crystal is as buggy as it can be. It's the Windows ME version of Reporting software. Good luck!

Comment: I founder if the delay is the timeout period for the database connection. What kind of connection is it, anyway? How are you providing data to the report at runtime?

Comment: @noa The connection is an Oracle Server connection. After the load, I'm applying new logon info to each of the tables, then I'm setting a parameter on the report, and then I export it to PDF. This all happens fairly quickly, though. It's the Load method that is slow.

Comment: Would you post the rest of your code? Wild-ass guess: do you need to provide the new logon information to the database connection before you call `ReportDocument.Load`?

Comment: We have seen similar issues (well, for MS SQL) when DNS is misconfigured...

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports takes a long time to load its DLLs at the first time you call a report. What [SAP](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports/index.epx) suggest is to load a dummy report at the first app excution using a thread or a background worker to get DLLs ready when calling your production reports.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a result of a number of effects. Firstly preloading the dlls will help but only for the first report. If lag continues to be a problem after dll preloading is introduced it is likely that the lag is being caused by the dlls having to ensure that the schema of the database you are connecting to matches that of the original database. This "should" only occur first time you run against the new database so it may help to pre-run some reports against the new database to ensure that they know that the data dictionaries are verified. CR is actually not all that buggy contrary to popular opinion, it is just quirky!